# How to format an sjPlot in pdf Rmarkdown?

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

I'm working on a project that requires a few descriptive tables. I created such table using sjPlot (used specifically sjt.xtab and sjt.df). When I knit the tables in my **R** markdown as a PDF, the tables are not formatted at all, and I'm instead left with a long list of variables. My YAML includes:

---

```
output: pdf_document
graphics: yes
```

---

This didn't work for me as others have experienced. Does anyone have any idea how to ensure formatting works for sjPlot in pdf form?

Comment: the `sjt.()`-functions only return HTML-output, which simply does not render nicely to PDF. If you don't mind to use a workaround, you could knit to HTML, import to Writer / Word, and export to PDF then (if PDF is required). Else, you need to use other packages that also return LaTex when creating tables in knitr-documents.

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I really appreciate it. The workaround should be fine this time, and I'll use a different package for tables next time.

Comment: I just created a Github repo with a function to build tex and pdf versions of the sjPlot::tab_model() tables: https://github.com/gorkang/html2latex/ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent lot of time figuring out how to translate some tests output tables to decently looking tables in PDF output from Rmarkdown source. The solution that worked for me involved `pander`. For instance:

```
library(pander)
linearMod <- lm(var1 ~  var2, data = df)
summary(linearMod) %>% pander
```